# Estimate parameters using OLS in Linear regression (demonstration)

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model

I managed to demonstrate till the first part. The problem I'm facing is transforming it to look like the second part.

[image]

Comment: Distribute the $(X_i-\overline{X})$ through the $(Y_i-\overline{Y})$.  Then separate the two terms you get.

Comment: It's simple algebraic manipulation and I didn't see it, I feel stupid. Thank you very much @Bill !

Comment: It's not that simple.  The problem is that you look at the second and third parts, and say to yourself "that can't be true."  Or at least that's what I say to myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just so the question has an answer

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\overline {X}_n\right)\cdot\left(Y_i- \overline{Y} _n\right)=\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i+\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{X} _n\overline{Y}_n-\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\overline{X}_n-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\overline{Y} _n=\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i+n\cdot \overline{X} _n\overline{Y}_n-\overline{X}_n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-\overline{Y} _n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i+n\cdot \overline{X} _n\overline{Y}_n-\overline{X}_n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i-n\cdot\overline{Y} _n\overline{X} _n=\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i-\overline{X}_n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i=\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n X_iY_i-\overline{X}_n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i
\end{align}
Continue from here, but it's already clear the answer will be what one would expect.

Comment: This question must have about 100 answers on this site--it's just hard to search for them.

Comment: @whuber True, mostly because people often don't title their questions clearly. Perhaps we could formulate a canonical question on the whole OLS linear regression estimation (is there one already?).